# Does selection.call really return the selection in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

According to the docs `selection.call()` returns the current selection but when I test this I see differing behaviours.

The code:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .on("click", click)
                .call(force.drag);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; });
```

Should be identical to:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .on("click", click)
                .call(force.drag)
                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; });
```

But I see differing behaviours. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/timebandit/5dJaA/30/) is the fiddle. See lines 57 - 61. The text in the nodes disappears when the second form is used.

Comment: Your nodeEnter object in the fiddle is a selection of circle elements, not g elements, so you can't append text elements to that.

Comment: Ahhh, that's right, but in theory tacking on code onto the end of a 'call' is still valid right? I'll test it.

Comment: Yes, call returns the selection as advertised...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the d3 source...

```
d3_selectionPrototype.call = function(callback) {
  var args = d3_array(arguments);
  callback.apply(args[0] = this, args);
  return this;
};
```

`d3_selectionPrototype` is bunged onto the `__proto__` of every selection so `this` is the selection.

You can trace it ...

```
d3.select = function(node) {
  var group;
  if (typeof node === "string") {
    group = [d3_select(node, d3_document)];
    group.parentNode = d3_document.documentElement;

  } else {
    group = [node];
    group.parentNode = d3_documentElement(node);
  } 
return d3_selection([group]);
}
```

...

```
function d3_selection(groups) {
  d3_subclass(groups, d3_selectionPrototype);
  return groups;
}
```

...

```
var d3_subclass = {}.__proto__?

// Until ECMAScript supports array subclassing, prototype injection works well.
function(object, prototype) {
  object.__proto__ = prototype;
}:

// And if your browser doesn't support __proto__, we'll use direct extension.
function(object, prototype) {
  for (var property in prototype) object[property] = prototype[property];
};
```

Comment: I think I will look more into the actual dark swamps of the source in the future.

Comment: I recommend it! And it's not so dark, like anything else, it seems impossible at first but soon enough it will click. Just fork it on GIT and keep adding comments to your fork as you go is what I do.

Comment: I also tend to run my own fork when I'm developing so I can see my own comments if I need to trace, and, as I'm tracing, I add comments as I go. It's a nice way to lock in your learnings...